# change color in multiple graphs (quantmod package)

Tags: r, quantmod

I drew several graphs in one window, but they are hard to distinguish, how can I color them differently

```
library(quantmod)
library(xts)

len <- 20000

times <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 00:00:00"), length = len, by = "sec")

S1 <- as.xts(cumsum(rnorm(len)),order.by = times)
S1 <- to.period(S1,period = "minutes",k = 5,indexAt = 'startof')

S2 <- as.xts(cumsum(rnorm(len)),order.by = times)
S2 <- to.period(S2,period = "minutes",k = 5,indexAt = 'startof')

S3 <- as.xts(cumsum(rnorm(len)),order.by = times)
S3 <- to.period(S3,period = "minutes",k = 5,indexAt = 'startof')

chart_Series(S1)
add_Series(S2,on = 1)
add_Series(S3,on = 1)
```

[image]

I tried to apply `chart theme()` but it doesn't work for me

```
my <- chart_theme()
my$col$dn.col <- "blue"

chart_Series(S1,theme = my)

my$col$dn.col <- "red"
add_Series(S2,on = 1,theme = my)

my$col$dn.col <- "green"
add_Series(S3,on = 1,theme = my)
```